# formatting issue when de-serialize numeric field as string in Json.net

Tags: json.net

When I try to convert a `json` numeric field into C# string field, I get the following formatting issue:

Json format:

```
{"a":-7.0}
```

Corresponding C# class:

```
public class JsonReport
{
 public string a {get;set;}
}
```

when I call the method:

```
var obj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonReport>(strContent);
```

I expect the `obj.a` would be "-7.0", but it turn out to be "-7", which is not what I want , what should I set to fix the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a decimal value like this, it is usually best to wait until the last possible moment--that is, just before you are about to display the value to the end user--before formatting it to a string.  Waiting affords you the greatest flexibility in working with the value; you can do calculations with it, or decide to format it differently for different displays.  So my recommendation would be to change the `a` property in your `JsonReport` class to be a `double` or `decimal` (depending on your needs), then format the value later, when you are ready to output it.

All that said, if you really want to format the decimal value to a string during deserialization, you can do this with a custom JsonConverter.  Here is what it might look like:

```
class FloatToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken value = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (value.Type == JTokenType.Float)
        {
            // Adjust the formatting to your requirements
            return value.ToObject<double>().ToString("0.0#######;-0.0#######");
        }
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, decorate the class properties you want formatted with a `JsonConverter` attribute like this:

```
public class JsonReport
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FloatToStringConverter))]
    public string a { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize as normal:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonReport>(strContent);
Console.WriteLine(obj.a);
```

Output:

```
-7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

pass your json object as string

```
{"a":"-7.0"}
```

Change your C# class

```
public class JsonReport
{
   public string a {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to keep the raw format as string, I have rephrased the question.